Using multiple namespaces with i18next: files do not load properly
I am kind of new using i18next with React. I am currently working on building a personal website/portfolio with ReactJS/TS and want to translate content to English. I use JSON files to store my translations.
I'd like to keep things organised so I have several translation files in different folders:

My /public/locales/en and /public/locales/fr folders contain basic translations for my website (like buttons, page titles, text, etc.),
My /src/data/en and /src/data/fr folders contain data that I want to display dynamically (projects, skills and career milestones).

So far, "basic" translations work perfectly fine. With the help of this article and this one, I have created a LocaleSelector component that allows me to switch languages.
Things get trickier when it comes to dealing with repetitive data like those stored in my /data folder, because I cannot seem to get my translation files loaded and rendered properly.
I'll illustrate my issue with the projects.json use case.
Before using i18next, it was pretty straightforward: I had 1 file that I imported into my Projectscomponent, used .map() function to iterate and automatically render a ProjectElement component for each object in my array.
Now, I get the following error: TypeError: projectsList.map is not a function.
My projects.json file is structured as follows:
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "My project 1",
      "isComplete": true,
      "tasks": [
        "task1",
        "task2"
      ]
    }
// rest of code
]

My i18n.ts file is configured as follows:
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

import translationEN from '../public/locales/en/translation.json';
import milestonesEN from './data/en/milestones.json';
import projectsEN from './data/en/projects.json';
import skillsEN from './data/en/skills.json';

import translationFR from '../public/locales/fr/translation.json';
import milestonesFR from './data/fr/milestones.json';
import projectsFR from './data/fr/projects.json';
import skillsFR from './data/fr/skills.json';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: translationEN,
    milestones: milestonesEN,
    projects: projectsEN,
    skills: skillsEN,
  },
  fr: {
    translation: translationFR,
    milestones: milestonesFR,
    projects: projectsFR,
    skills: skillsFR,
  },
};

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    debug: true,
  });

export default i18n;

And this is my Projects component:

import { useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import ProjectElement from './ProjectElement';
import { Switch } from '../ui/switch';
import { Label } from '../ui/label';

import type { ProjectInterface } from '@/@types/dataTypes';

function Projects() {
  const { t } = useTranslation(['translation', 'projects']);

  const projectsList: ProjectInterface[] = t('projects', {
    returnObjects: true,
  });

  // console.log('projects list:', projectsList) >>> returns: 'projects';

  return (
    <main className="projects-container">
      <div className="projects-title">
        <h2 className="page-title">{t('projects.title')}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="projects-content">
        <div className="projects-list">
          {projectsList.map((project) => {
                return <ProjectElement key={project.id} project={project} />;
              )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Projects;

I was expecting my console.log to return an array, but it simply returns a string (hence, the errorTypeError: projectsList.map is not a function). The thing is, I tried to console.log my projectsEN data in the i18n.ts file and it worked. I probably have made a mistake in configuring and loading my namespaces or i18n, but I really do not understand where.
I went through the official documentation and several other resources, they did not help.
Do you have any clue about this issue?
Many thanks in advance for your help!
